# How to get Bitmap response Count/Size (Android)

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I know this might be pretty textbook but i just can wrap my head around it just yet.
So i'm requesting several bitmaps using volley image request and i get a bitmap response. What i want to do is iterate through the response using a for loop and do something with what i've got. i just can't figure out how to get the length of the response.

i know if it were a jsonObject, you can do response.length. i want that equivalent for bitmap or some other process..

```
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(uri, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES; i++) {

                //do stuff 
                 file.createNewFile();
                 outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                 outputStream.flush();
                 outputStream.close();

            }


        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're confused-  that request you have there requests a single bitmap.  Are you maybe using multiple requests?  If so, there's nothing to loop there.

Comment: my uri is from a json object and it has links to 10 images... so there has to be a loop to retrieve and save all 10 images

Comment: Not in this section of the code. The loop would be making 10 requests, not in a single response

Comment: let me update the code so you see what i'm talking about...

Comment: You don't need to update the code.  You're talking about looping in the wrong place.  A single ImageRequest downloads a single Bitmap.  You need to send multiple requests in order to get multiple Bitmaps.  You would not loop in the response to a single bitmap..

Comment: see the url, http://api.androidhive.info/json/glide.json house the links to the images. ive looped through the jsonobject to get the url for images. now i'm  parsing this url, which should be in the form of an array now to the image request. so i need to do for each item in the array, fetch the image and save it.

Comment: Thanks, i think i see what you are talking about. The other loop was just repetitive.